# Covering space of a graph is again a graph - why??

Tags: graph-theory, covering-spaces

i want to prove the statement in the heading. Thus given graph $G$ and a covering space $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow G$ to prove that $\tilde{X}$ is also a graph. My idea was to take $\tilde{E}=p^{-1}(E)$ and $\tilde{V}=p^{-1}(V)$ with $E$ and $V$ the sets of edges and vertices resp. But how to go further? Have i have to use the lifting properties??`Can someone give me help with this question?! Thanks

Comment: This is shown here: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/conferences/GSTGC/Adeel_Sat4pm_1024.pdf

Comment: thanks, but what about the third point of the proof? I can't imagine how to write this down on a good way?!

Comment: @gt6989b any idea how to get the pdf you mention? It's not available anymore.

Comment: @Zero unfortunately not

Comment: @gt6989b Do you remember the proof? I'd be nice if you could write it down. I have some ideas but nothing concrete.

Comment: unfortunately not... haven't seen this in 3 years...